# How can I escape this string properly?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a complex regex I want to apply. Here is my pattern:

```
/(?:^|\s|[\.(\+\-\,])(?:\$?)\$((?:[0-9]+(?=[a-z])|(?![0-9\.\:\_\-]))(?:[a-z0-9]|[\_\.\-\:](?![\.\_\.\-\:]))*[a-z0-9]+)/i
```

How can I declare this as a String and make sure everything is escaped?

Comment: Step one: Simplify you pattern by getting rid on unnecessary backslashes and groups: `/(?:^|[\s.(+,-])\$?\$((?:[0-9]+(?=[a-z])|(?![0-9.:_-]))(?:[a-z0-9]|[.:_-](?![.:_-]))*[a-z0-9]+)/i`

Comment: Do you have any issues with `Pattern.quote()`?

Comment: @Gumbo: Who says it is unnecessary? If he has to replace one of the groups, he really need groups.

Comment: @Martijn Courteaux: `(?:\$?)` *is* unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me as if there's a lot of unnecessary stuff in that regex

1. Something like `(?:\$?)` is the same as just `\$?`
2. There's no need to "protect" the ".", "_", ",", or "+" characters in a square-bracket group

So what you really could have is:

```
/(?:^|\s|[.(+\-,])\$?\$((?:[0-9]+(?=[a-z])|(?![0-9.:_\-]))(?:[a-z0-9]|[_.\-:](?![._\-:]))*[a-z0-9]+)/i
```

As for putting it in a string, all you really have to worry about here are the backslashes.  Those need to be doubled ("\").  The outer "/" characters would be dropped, and the trailing "i" modifier would be passed into the `Pattern.compile()` method.

Answer (score 2):

As long as a somewhat static solution will suffice, and if you are using Eclipse IDE you can choose to have String escaped correctly when pasting from clipboard.

Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Typing -> [x] Escape text when pasting...

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to test that pattern, I suggest you look into using a regex tool like [gskinner](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/). It lets you put in a pattern, a string, and highlights the matches.